# Snowflake new UI - Load data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Has anyone tried loading data from new UI in Snowflake? There is a load data option in classic web interface; however, I cannot find anything like that in new UI.
I understand focus of new UI and Snowsight is towards data analytics, wondering if load data option has been removed from new UI!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowsight doesn't have yet built in the functionality of loading data as in Classic UI.

There is a plan to add this functionality, but I don't have any timeliness yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Loading Data Using the Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/user-guide/data-load-web-ui)

> You can use Snowsight or Classic Console to load files with structured data (e.g. CSV, TSV) or semi-structured data (e.g. JSON, Avro, ORC, Parquet, or XML).

[image]

[image]